# How to get the status of a AWS/Lambda function with boto3?

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3

Is there any way using boto3 to discover if a lambda function has finished successfully or not? Generally what is the best way to wait for a lambda to complete?

The lambda function is invoked asynchronously (so `InvocationType="Event"`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that the Lambda was successful and possibly do something with the result, you need a synchronous invocation. In Lambda you use the `RequestResponse` invocation type for that.

Below you can see an example for that.

```py
import boto3

def run_lambda_and_wait_for_it() -> bool:
    lambda_client = boto3.client("lambda")

    response = lambda_client.invoke(
        FunctionName="LambdaDemo",
        InvocationType="RequestResponse",  # Synchronous Invocation
    )

    return response["StatusCode"] == 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    invocation_successful = run_lambda_and_wait_for_it()
    print(f"Was the invocation successful? {invocation_successful}")
```

```sh
$ python3 boto3_lambda_invoke.py
Was the invocation successful? True
```

**Reference:**

- [boto3 invoke docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke)
- [General Invoke Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html)

---

### Update:

Is the error count metric sufficient for your use case? You can also get that from CloudWatch directly.

[image: Lambda error and success rate]

Comment: sorry my question wasn't complete. I have updated it. Thanks

Comment: That detail was kind of important :D

Comment: You could check out the error count as a metric, I don't know what exactly it is you're trying to find out @Randomize

Answer (score 0):

@Randomize

I have to make the assumption that your Lambda function MAY NOT finish successfully.  Why might that be?

1. It is processing input from other systems outside of your control
2. It may time out if it receives too much data
3. You may exceed your [concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html)

Lets assume [concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html) is a broader topic.  So, lets assume you have a function that fails occasionally.

Consider the following Lambda Function:

```
import time
import random

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sleep_time = random.randint(1,20)
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
    
    return {
        "sleepTime": sleep_time,
        "result": int(event['x']/event['y'])
    }
```

Obviously, this could fail for different reasons: divide by zero and type errors (I set the timeout to 21 seconds).

One way we can track failures is a [Dead Letter Queue (DLQ)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#dlq).

Here I create a queue: `$ aws sqs create-queue --queue-name divideFunctionDLQ`

I then attach a policy allowing the Lambda Function to publish to the queue in question and then I set the Lambda Function to use it as a dead letter queue:

`$ aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name divideFunction --dead-letter-config TargetArn=arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:************:divideFunctionDLQ` (Account # redacted from ARN)

I can then trigger some invokations:

```
$ aws lambda invoke --function-name divideFunction --invocation-type Event --payload '{"x": 16, "y": 2}' out.json
$ aws lambda invoke --function-name divideFunction --invocation-type Event --payload '{"x": 16, "y": 0}' out.json
$ aws lambda invoke --function-name divideFunction --invocation-type Event --payload '{"x": "a", "y": 1}' out.json
$ aws lambda invoke --function-name divideFunction --invocation-type Event --payload '{"x": 10, "y": 5}' out.json
```

And now we can retreive using our DLQ:

```
$ aws sqs receive-message --max-number-of-messages 10 --queue-url https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/829583023482/divideFunctionDLQ
{
    "Messages": [
        {
            "MessageId": "237c9c2d-7819-4fe5-b9ea-37e98492a937",
            "ReceiptHandle": "AQEBIEtrcofsSAVfqL75/aerGwZiJ/4QXfBv1awBwVsnVCv3x5Qnex/nySgHLukCfuIt8YmWDAbEjOsj2M/IN1Grm+zRY5eenOkRvJkFUBURkrK2JBUQuOTx1rnkO2N3YJQlNvEwiKPscbuemNNoEq7MRVNLhxIxjOuhS0kjTxhYhtZZhVwSel0wkbN5dVsfkmqI/uaDO/mzGD4n70pKZM3cqL+GFTJhnvgREKur80D0AKNrr0NGHkcL/xJBz5G8FRfWqaoe2ApJ7vC0iGdrOgXWWlHFz9k2xutMe5WCa2IwiwcHVP794F1PfsWsQZDsmT35nJsXFFhsSnyLt3b4Nld/ZcF22jhogOkkktr2S0DxGnGP6Wx8Hqds8Xmhj3/pdLHr4LR8nkYWUDBnl+cfEUa6/A==",
            "MD5OfBody": "313101ffd6812ca97574075448169c1b",
            "Body": "{\"x\": \"a\", \"y\": 1}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Why would you want to run functions asynchronously?  They might be doing jobs like ETL or encoding/re-encoding, which might lend themselves well to an asyncronus model.

Comment: yes for ETL jobs and yes processing input from other systems outside of my control. As simple alternative in some case a simple S3 file broker can work too.